# user gets access denied when adding new document in folder

Tags: folder, access-denied

In my SharePoint 2013 environment I have a site where the admin user group has  design rights + security management rights. A readers permission group has read access on the site. I have a document library with one folder. On the folder I break the inheritance and give the readers group contribute access.

When the user from the readers groups wants to add a new document (Ribbon --> new document --> document) he gets a pop-up with an access denied message.

Why can't the user add a new document with contribute access?

Comment: Just click on the folder's Ellipsis (...) and click "share with". Then click on "check permissions". Type the user and check what permissions he/she has on the folder. After all, Library is nothing but a List. You need permissions on lists to add items.

Comment: I have checked the permissions (Shared With on the folder) and the user has contribute rights.

Answer (score 0):

A folder is an item, and is not considered a different instance of the list.  On the list, your readers still have Read privilages and will not be able to add the documents.  They will be able to edit the folder with the Contribute level permission you have provided, but will still not be able to add items to it because they do not have write permissions to the list.

I would suggest creating a sepatate security group with a custom permission level to allow the addition of documents to the specified library.  You can still use the item permissions for them to be able to see only curtain items/folders on the list, but they will need to be able to have the permissions for them to add items regardless.

Comment: Hi lazoDev, Thanks for you respons. While the user isn't able to add documents in the folder, he can use the upload button next to the new document. When he uses + new document button above the list, he can also add documents.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure I have tested this. And did the same flow as you mentioned and given user contribute rights.

If user is seeing New, Upload option means they have sufficient access. I am able to create a new document, also I am able to upload existing documents. If this is not yet resolved, please let me know specific steps you are seeing access denied.

thanks

-Praveen.